# How to Fix Could not autowire. No beans of error in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, spring-security

[image]

How can I solve this error. I'm New to Spring-boot

Comment: do not post images of code or error messages, it is not allowed on stack overflow https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 4):

As I can see the spring unable to find the bean `UserDetailsServiceImpl`, there might be couple of reason for it.

First, you might forgot to put `@Service` annotation on top of the class `UserDetailsServiceImpl`. Also, as the context is about Spring security so make sure that this class `UserDetailsServiceImpl` must implement the interface `UserDetailsService`

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
}
```

Second, spring might be unable to scan this folder. So make sure spring IOC must scan this package while intialization and configure the bean.

Answer (score 1):

In order to `@Autowired` a bean instance, a class should be decorated with Spring stereotype annotation like `@Component`, `@Service`, `@Repository`, `@Controller` or `@Indexed`. Just by decorating the class with one of these role annotations, you can use `@Autowired` to bind with the instance.

Otherwise, if none of these annotations are used, your class instances, you have to manually registered to the `BeanFactory` like this;

```
@Configuration
public class SomeClass {
    
    ...

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl()
    }
}
```

This answer just talk about your specific question, but you get to find out why `@Configuration` is used in preceeding example. Define scopes for bindings, singleton (one instance for the application) is the default scope in Spring, you should define scopes for beans if they should be in different scope on your requirements.